# USB Startup Disk Creator doesn't open!

Tags: usb-creator

I have a problem. **I am trying to open USB Startup Disk Creator** (System>Administration>USB Startup Disk Creator) **but it doesn't open**. 
 **What should i do to open it?**

Please help  me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try from terminal:
   sudo usb-creator-gtk

Comment: I tried from Terminal by typing 'sudo usb-creator-gtk' but Terminal show me: command not found.

Answer (score 1):

What are the results of:

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

This should install the `usb-creator-gtk` package, and all the packages it depends on.